# Is it possible to expand the partition created on Ubuntu trial (live USB) flash drive?

Tags: ubuntu, partition

Yesterday I created a Live USB Ubuntu boot flash drive (16GB) and booted up with no problems.  It runs great on my i7, 8GB laptop.

**Android Studio Test**

I'm attempting to test running Android Studio and Android Emulator from Ubuntu on my 8GB RAM laptop so I downloaded and attempted to install it.

**Out of Space**

Studio installs successfully but when the installer got to the installation of the emulator it failed and said I was out of space.

**Tried Again On 64GB Flash Drive**

I tried again on 64GB flash drive and got the same error.

From what I could tell the trial installation was limited to a 4GB partition even though there was more space on the drive.  Is that correct?  Is it limited to 4GB partition?

Is there some way to expand the partition on the trial so I can get this to work?

Is it possible to install the "full" booting version on to the 64 GB stick?

Comment: This is a perfectly acceptable question for this SE site, but you might also consider checking www.AskUbuntu.com, another SE site and the official(?) Ubuntu community support site.

Comment: @0xSheepdog Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is doubtful you can *easily* do this. Depending on the format of the Live Ubuntu image, it may be loading the entire operating system to a ram based tmpfs volume. You would have to change the way the system loader builds the tmpfs and a lot of other things.

It is probably easier to boot the original 16GB flash drive and perform a normal install *to the 64GB flash drive*. This is definitely doable, but might take some extra configuration to work. Then if you choose not to stay with Ubuntu, you simply wipe the 64GB flash drive.

Comment: This is the answer. Installing on and booting from USB flash drives is pretty much trivial with Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if it were possible to do that (boot from 16GB and install onto 64GB). I will try this tonight.

Answer (score 2):

Live installs are not suitable for installing software.

What I think you need is:

1. [A full install of the OS on the USB.](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/11/install-real-ubuntu-os-usb-drive/)
2. [Make a USB persistent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051543/how-to-make-a-live-ubuntu-18-04-usb-with-a-persistent-storage-of-more-than-4gb). In this case, you create a partition where the data is stored, and pass the flag (in some OS) `persistent` to the kernel in the GRUB menu. Or depending the tool you use to create your USB it will have the option to create persistence, like [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/).

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I will try this tonight.